# Replace column values based on a filter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Given this list

```
a = [a,d]
```

Give a dataset as such

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| a | cat |
| b | fish |
| c | dog |
| d | cat |

If the **id** items of the dataset are found in the list **a**, then I need to change the related **type** item, if not leave the same type item

End result

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| a | bird |
| b | fish |
| c | dog |
| d | bird |

This code is not working

```
df["type"] = np.where(df["id"].isin(a), df["type"].replace("bird"), df["type"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only set `bird` if match condition, `replace` is not necessary here if need set to same values:

```
df["type"] = np.where(df["id"].isin(a), "bird", df["type"])
```